# Material-UI Drawer with Flexbox horizontal scroll not working on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, material-ui, mobile-safari

I am trying to scroll horizontally inside of a Drawer component from Material-UI. It works fine outside of the Drawer, but not inside of it.

I have tested it everywhere else that I can and it works, but it does not work on Safari on an iPhone. I have tried on a physical device as well as the Simulator.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-qqdo2?file=/demo.js

```js
function Scroller() {
  return (
    <Box overflow="hidden" bgcolor="primary.main">
      <Box display="flex" overflow="auto hidden">
        {[...new Array(50)].map((_, i) => (
          <Box key={i} p={1}>
            <Chip label="Test Chip" color="secondary" />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround, at least. Seems to be something with the `SwipeableDrawer` that's disabling the scrolling. Switching it out to `Drawer` instead works just fine.

I updated the example to show both drawers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `display: unset !important`, it worked for me.
Example:

```
.MuiDrawer-paper {
    display: unset !important;
}
```